# Error arising when using \typeout & \meaning with \midrule

Tags: debugging, terminal-output

In order to facilitate debugging some experimental code, I created a version of `\typeout` that will break its content into multiple lines:

```
%% dummy macro for simulating newlines in output to terminal
\def\my@linefeed{}
\def\mytypeout#1\my@linefeed#2\@nil{%%
  \typeout{\detokenize{#1}}%%
  % \typeout{\meaning#1}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
    \mytypeout#2\@nil
  \fi}
```

I would use it as follows:

```
\mytypeout ==> A testing mytypeout on its own\my@linefeed
           ==> B testing mytypeout on its own\my@linefeed
           ==> C testing mytypeout on its own\my@linefeed
           ==> D testing mytypeout on its own\my@linefeed
           ==> E testing mytypeout on its own\my@linefeed
           ==> F testing mytypeout on its own\my@linefeed\@nil
```

my `\mytypeout{...}` seemed to work fine until I started using it in conjunction with `booktabs`.

The following MWE compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
%%\let\my@linefeed\relax%% --> raises errors!
%% dummy macro for simulating newlines in output to terminal
\def\my@linefeed{}
\def\mytypeout#1\my@linefeed#2\@nil{%%
  \typeout{\detokenize{#1}}%%
  % \typeout{\meaning#1}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
    \mytypeout#2\@nil
  \fi}

%% `\space`s added to make `\typeout` more readable
\def\my@row@of@table{%%
  First column matter \space 
  & 
  \expandonce\x \space 
  \noexpand\\
  %% Neither \meaning nor \detokenize raise an error
  %% if this next line is commented out
  % \noexpand\midrule
  \noexpand\my@linefeed
  }

\def\full@agenda{}
\def\build@agenda{%%
  \foreach \x in \list@of@agenda@items {%%
    \xdef\full@agenda{%%
      \expandonce\full@agenda
      \my@row@of@table}%%
    \expandafter\mytypeout\full@agenda\my@linefeed\@nil
    \typeout{---DONE----}%%
  }}

\def\setagenda#1{%%
  \bgroup
    \def\list@of@agenda@items{#1}%%
    \build@agenda
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
      \toprule
      \full@agenda          
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%%
  \egroup
  \def\full@agenda{}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\setagenda{
    {A Line of random content},
    {B Not too involved math: $x\cdot y$ },
    {C Some more random text.},
    {D Random },
    {E Hello world},
    {F no more}
    }

\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the line

```
  % \noexpand\midrule
```

then in order to get the above MWE to compile, I had to change the definition of `\mytypeout`.  Namely, I had to change

```
\typeout{\meaning#1}
```

to

```
\typeout{\detokenize{#1}}
```

I can't quite figure out what's going on here.  I tried isolating the error by testing the following code

```
%% No problems with `\typeout` + `\meaning` in either of the next two examples:
%% example #1
\def\aetemp{\midrule}
\typeout{TEMP(A):\meaning\aetemp}
%% example #2
\def\aetemp{\noexpand\midrule}
\typeout{TEMP(B):\meaning\aetemp}
```

But I didn't get any errors.

What's happening here?  What am I missing?

Comment: I think I get what's going on here.  I think the problem is that `\meaning` works on one token.  Instead I'm applying `\meaning` to `#1` which is a sequence of tokens.

Comment: Moderators, should I keep this question posted?  Or is this too localized?

Comment: I am not a moderator, but vote for keep it open – I have learned something from it. I'd suggest to add an answer.

Comment: If you want sensible answers, you should make an example that shows the error, or give ***precise*** instructions for modifying the presented code. If I leave `\noexpand\midrule` commented and uncomment the `\typeout{\meaning#1}` line I get several errors.

Comment: @egreg I see what you mean.  I had tried improving the answer and in the process didn't notice that I broke the code either way you went with `\typeout{\meaning#1)` and `\noexpand\midrule`.

Comment: @egreg Now I'm really perplexed.  Going through my revision history, I can't seem to find any version in which `\typeout{\meaning#1}` worked.  Now I'm clueless about what I was doing to think it was working.  :(  Either way though, ultimately I was misunderstanding how `\meaning` works.

Answer (score 1):

If I add `\showtokens{#1}` in the definition of `\mytypeout`, just before the `\typeout`, I get, for the first call,

```
> First column matter  & A Line of random content \\ .
\mytypeout ...@linefeed #2\@nil ->\showtokens {#1}
                                                  \typeout {\detokenize {#1}...
l.62     }
```

This clearly means that `\meaning#1` is completely out of place, because it would just act on `F`, with an expansion such as

```
The character F
```

So `\typeout{\meaning#1}` is definitely not what you want. You *can* use `\meaning`, but like

```
  \begingroup\def\next{#1}%
  \typeout{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\next}%%
  \endgroup
```

This will give as output

```
First column matter  & A Line of random content \\ 
First column matter  & B Not too involved math: $x\cdot y$  \\ 
First column matter  & C Some more random text. \\ 
First column matter  & D Random  \\ 
First column matter  & E Hello world \\ 
First column matter  & {F no more}  \\
```

which of course is no different from what you get with the `\detokenize` version.